# Why was my blog post inserted lot's of ad links by others?

Tags: security, hacks

I found that my blog posts are inserted lot's of ad links, I'm using WordPress 2.9.2, is there a known security vulnerability in it?
A screenshot : I post some codes on my blog, the ad links are inserted into them.

[image]

I delete them by hand several days ago, and I found that they're back again!

Comment: We're now at 3.1.3 and there were many minor versions since 2.9.2 due to vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ign although, to be fair, something like this is more likely the fault of cheap/insecure hosting. I don't remember any of the security releases fixing a hole big enough to allow this kind of a hack.

Comment: Agreed, not blaiming WP. Just saying that you can't even discard that since he's running a one year old build, like @TheDeadMedic said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've been hacked. In all fairness, you're running a version that is [over a year old](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions) - it's always best practice to upgrade as soon as you can.

I would advise reading through the [FAQ on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked). I also stumbled across this rather concise [step-by-step](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/), though I would advise it's for the intermediate user (use of SQL and FTP is required).

Comment: You should also notify your host. Most of the security patches since 2.9.2 relate to logged-in users. None would allow this level of injection. Poorly-coded plugins or theme might let this in but the most likely cause is insecure hosting. If this blog is in a shared-hosting environment it is important that the host is notified.

Comment: OK, I updated my wordpress to the latest version...waiting for the hacking come again..